# Qual é a forma mais recomendável e performática de se manipular datas no PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, data

No PHP podemos manipular datas utilizando funções como **date**, **strtotime**, **mktime** e etc. e a partir da versão 5.3 dele podemos manipular datas de forma orientada a objeto com as classes **DateTime**, **DateInterval**, **DatePeriod** e etc.

Usando funções:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Usando classes:

```
<?php

$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');

$currentDateTime = new DateTime('now', $timeZone);
echo $currentDateTime->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Qual seria a forma mais recomendável e performática de se manipular datas no PHP, seira usando de forma orientada a objetos ou estruturada?

Answer (score 3):

A melhor forma, depende daquilo que sua aplicação requerer, porque tanto as funções `data`, `strtime` como a classe `DateTime` são qualificadas. Se ela for orientada então usa classes, se não, usa a forma estruturada mesmo.

Tanto que o povo fala de *DRY*, e nesse caso não imaginaria criar uma classe para horas e a data, ficar digitando `new` vezes e vezes, quando o próprio website seria algo simples, e provavelmente só faria uso dela, para imprimir o ano no rodapé *(único no site todo)* e quando fosse para inserir datas no banco.

> **??**: No *php* classes auxiliares, são normalmente estáticas por serem convenientes, não ?.